# How to extract a whole database schema using only ODBC access?

Tags: schema, odbc, dump

I need to migrate an old proprietary database (custom database based on a Btrieve engine) to a newer system . All I have to access this database is an ODBC driver that works pretty well. When I connect to the database, I only see views but still the database documentation provides the table names and I am able to access them even though the driver does not show them.

Unfortunately the database documentation is quite poor and does not allow me to generate the full schema. Some information like the column precision and scale is missing.

So is there a tool that would allow me to read the full database schema and dump it to a file ?

I really just need a description of the the tables like table name, column name, datatype, precision, scale and optionally comments. I don't even need relationship and keys. For the rest, I have enough skill to process those information and generate a script for my destination database.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from chat in "The Heap"...

Visio can reverse engineer a database. However, I assume thus needs to read metadata or system tables to get everything (keys, DRI, datatypes the works).

This old MSDN article may help ["Migrating Btrieve Applications to MS SQL Server 7.0"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966479.aspx%22) too

Comment: I forgot to mention that my goal is to simply make a 1 to 1 migration. Relations and keys are not needed.